# Why does a BroadcastReceiver work without an instance?

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.forms, localbroadcastmanager

In [this tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/background-audio-streaming-with-xamarin-android/#crayon-589362d7332c4926902346)  a class derives from `BroadcastReceiver`. It then receives messages. How? This is just a definition of a class, not an instance of it!

And after we figure that out - how do we *prevent* this from happening so that we can use this class with a `LocalBroadcastManager`, limiting it to the app only? (Not with the same exact case as in the tutorial, of course, because that's a message that's *not* from the app.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use annotations like `[Service]` and `[BroadcastReceiver]` etc, the Xamarin.Android compiler automatically adds the required sections into the generated AndroidManifest.xml, which in case of the `[BroadcastReceiver]` it starts working because of the `[IntentFilter]`.

You can see generated manifest at `obj\Debug\AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thanks. So how do we prevent this from happening if we want to use a `LocalBroadcastManager`?

Comment: OK. Never mind. I got it. Just supply the IntentFilter by code with the LocalBroadcastManager, I assume.